# How to Display Thousands/Millions of different background images

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas

How do I make a webpage load thousands or even millions of different pictures as HTML background without crashing or slowing down the browser?

The images can be created dynamically, or linked to its folder. I was able to do that for up to 1000 images per canvas, and add up much more canvas, but at 30 canvas, which is 30,000 images the browser stops to respond(slowish).

FYI: The images must be displayed all at once.

```
<html>
 <body>
      <script>
      var cInt=0;
      var loopCInt=0;
      while (loopCInt<3){
       var canvasName = document.createElement("canvas");
       canvasName.setAttribute('width', "1000");
       canvasName.setAttribute('height', "1000");
       var canvasIdName="myCanvas"+cInt;
       canvasName.setAttribute('id', canvasIdName);
       document.body.appendChild(canvasName);
        var c = document.getElementById(canvasIdName);
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var i = 0;
        var right=0;
        var tops=0;
        var goDown=0;
        while (i <= 1000) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.rect(right, goDown, 30, 30);
          ctx.fillStyle = '#'+Math.random().toString(16).slice(-6);
          ctx.fill();
          i++;
          right=right+30;
          tops++;
          if (tops==30){
            goDown=goDown+30;
            right=0;
            tops=0;
          }
        }

      loopCInt++;
      cInt++;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can't really, but you can try loading them as one image by resizing them and combining them with like an online tool; The server will crash if you have it load that many images at one time.

Comment: I'm saying you should try to fuse as many as you can, so that you can reach your ultimate goal of 1 million

Comment: Are tou trying to DDoS or something? Also, "without slowing down the browser"? You don't need code, you need a computer from NASA.

Comment: xD D.Pardal you got it right there.

Comment: Use WebGL and skip Canvas2D. Also don't spam more canvases than you need. Also don't do this on a public-facing website.

Comment: @D.Pardal I guess [http://priority.widgetmatic.com/JS_Mosaic2/] or [http://www.falconsriseup.com/] are using computer from NASA? That is similar to what i want to achieve, as you can see about 36,000 images without any performance issue, they even boast of more than 5 million pictures. Mine should be easier because my pictures are to be random in a pattern not necessarily being in a mosaic form.

Comment: @RandomChannel Check my reply to D.Pardal check the links.

Comment: About http://priority.widgetmatic.com/JS_Mosaic2 : That's just one image. As many people sayed, you cannot have millions of pictues, but you can fuse them into a single image,as you can see in the network tab; About http://falconsriseup.com : That's again one image. You are only able to zoom in and don't loose quality because when you zoom, the browser loads only the part you zoomed in with greater quality. **It's never all loaded at once**.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to load the 1000 images, but If you need a background that frequently changes. You can number your images from (1 to 1000). Then use javascript to randomly select 10 images. In this case, a visitor will see 10 different backgrounds per session.